# Reason for isotropy in amorphous substances

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

I'd be thankful if someone explains why amorphous substances are said to be isotropic and crystalline substances anisotropic

Comment: Not a bad question, but if you can clarify a little bit (narrow the scope), it will help you get a better answer. For example, some crystalline solids are isotropic. And there are probably corner cases (in any event) in which the statements don't apply in re: one or the other being isotropic or anisotropic.

Comment: Related: [How can diamond have a fixed refractive index?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37202/7951)